# Is not a known variable in PostgreSQL while writing procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I am trying to write a procedure in PostgreSQL by following these [instrunctions (No Value Returned)](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions) and my procedure/function is:

```
create or replace function flip_payment()
    returns void as $$
    begin
        -- drop any previous working table
        drop table if exists meta.fk_payment_copy;
        -- insert the unique row into fk_payment_temp
        SELECT distinct settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, wsn, 
               order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
               cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
               sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
               protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
               commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
               cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
               reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
               storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
               sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share 
         into fk_payment_copy 
         from fk_payment_temp;
         -- empty the fk_payment_temp table
         truncate table fk_payment_temp;
         -- Insert the final filter data into  fk_payment from copy table
         INSERT INTO fk_payment(
            settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, wsn, 
            order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
            cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
            sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
            protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
            commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
            cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
            reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
            storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
            sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share)
            SELECT settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, wsn, 
               order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
               cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
               sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
               protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
               commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
               cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
               reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
               storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
               sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share
          FROM fk_payment_copy;
          -- delete copy table
          drop table fk_payment_copy;
          -- rechecking for duplication
          SELECT min(id) as id, settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, 
               wsn, order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
               cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
               sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
               protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
               commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
               cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
               reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
               storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
               sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share
          into fk_payment_copy
          FROM fk_payment 
          group by  settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, 
               wsn, order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
               cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
               sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
               protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
               commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
               cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
               reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
               storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
               sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share;

               truncate table fk_payment;

               --final data
               INSERT INTO fk_payment(
                id, settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, 
                wsn, order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
                cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
                sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
                protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
                commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
                cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
                reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
                storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
                sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share)
                SELECT id, settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, 
                   wsn, order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
                   cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
                   sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
                   protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
                   commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
                   cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
                   reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
                   storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
                   sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share
                FROM fk_payment_copy;

                drop table fk_payment_copy;




    end;
    $$ language plpgsql;
```

It is giving an error:
    ERROR:  "fk_payment_copy" is not a known variable

```
LINE 18:    into fk_payment_copy 

               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: "fk_payment_copy" is not a known variable 

SQL state: 42601 

Character: 1010
```

This query is running correctly without procedure:

```
 SELECT distinct settlement_ref_no, order_type, fulfilment_type, seller_sku, wsn, 
               order_id, order_item_id, order_date, dispatch_date, delivery_date, 
               cancellation_date, settlement_date, order_status, quantity, order_item_value, 
               sale_transaction_amount, discount_transaction_amount, refund, 
               protection_fund, total_marketplace_fee, service_tax, settlement_value, 
               commission_rate, commission, payment_rate, payment_fee, fee_discount, 
               cancellation_fee, fixed_fee, emi_fee, total_weight, shipping_fee, 
               reverse_shipping_fee, shipping_zone, token_of_apology, pick_and_pack_fee, 
               storage_fee, removal_fee, invoice_id, invoice_date, invoice_amount, 
               sub_category, total_offer_amount, my_offer_share, flipkart_offer_share 
         into fk_payment_copy 
         from fk_payment_temp;
```

here `fk_payment_copy` I've already deleted .

Is this query returning any thing which I have to declare?

Comment: The compiler confuses this with a `select into variable`. Use `create table ... as select ...` instead (which is recommended anyway because it's the way this is defined in the SQL standard: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Comment: did you mean first i have to create table then insert the data and delete the table

Comment: No. Read the manual. `create new_table table as select .. from ..` is the same as the (non-standard) `select ... into new_table from ..` both create a new table based on the result of a select statement.